# Why didn't Madara start his own plan when he was still young?

Tags: naruto

I've seen the newest episodes of the anime, and I was thinking:

I understand that he didn't have the Rinnegan right after the battle with Hashirama, but still, I can't imagine that his recovery from that battle would be so long. He remained alive, and he was the strongest Uchiha, and one of the strongest shinobi in the world (and now with the cells of Hashirama), so why wait for someone (because Obito got to him by chance) if you can start what you want, when you want? With his Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, he could have built an organization like the Akatsuki, and played in the shadows, just as Obito did. In this way he could have time to search for a pupil, and at the same time, the organization members would search for the Tailed Beasts, and after defeating them, keep them in a "vegetative state" until Madara awakens his Rinnegan to manipulate the Gedo Statue and collect the Bijuu's before he dies (note that he's able to steal the Gedo Statue's power, so with Tailed Beasts inside it, he could have been much stronger, despite his age).

Then pass the Rinnegan to the pupil-> Rinne Tensei-> resurrected Madara has his youth and force back, plus the Tailed Beasts are already in his possession. (And MAYBE even his pupil would've survived and both of them would possess the Rinnegan)-> straight way to Tsuki no Me plan.

Comment: the black zetsu is a part of him. so you can say that madara was indeed involved in his plan quite early, in fact just before he died, he created the black zetsu. and it could control obito. so it was like madara did everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Madara didn't know he was going to awaken the Rinnegan. He knew about the story with the Sage of Six Paths and the Juubi, he also probably knew about the existence of the Eternal Tsukuyomi. But without the Rinnegan, his plan couldn't have succeeded at all (because the Rinnegan is needed for the Gedo Mazo).

Since Madara didn't know he was going to awaken the Rinnegan, or what the requirements were, he couldn't have started his plan.

Sure, in retrospect, if he had known he would awaken the Rinnegan at a later point, starting to collect the Bijuu early might have been a clever move.

---

Note that even his current plan had flaws in it:

- Obito never planned to resurrect Madara. It was Kabuto who made the fatal mistake of reanimating him (having been tempted by Black Zetsu with Madara's corpse), and thinking he could control him. Obito's plan was to complete the Infinite Tsukuyomi himself, and create a world in which Rin lives.

Comment: but if it's true,what you said,that "he didn't know he was going to awaken the Rinnegan", then why did he fused his body with Hashirama's cells, and why did he dreamed about the Tsuki no Me plan?(because, I can't imagine that Madara invented to accomplish this plan just after he awakened the Rinnegan)..so if he knew the story about what did you mention above, he must have started this whole thing right after the battle at the Valley of the End

Comment: He implanted the cells to recover, not awaken the Rinnegan.

Comment: @Rinneg4n - Let's say Madara infused Hashirama's cells with an idea of awakening the Rinnegan. But he wasn't sure if that was the actual requirement to awaken the Rinnegan. Since nobody had the Rinnegan other than Rikudu Senin, it was all a myth until Madara awakened it. He wasn't sure that he would definitely awaken it and thus he didn't get on with the job of collecting Bijuus, though Zetsu (black and white) were essentially created with *Tsuki no Me plan* in mind.

Comment: "Obito never planned to resurrect Madara. It was Kabuto who made the fatal mistake of reanimating him, and thinking he could control him. Obito's plan was to complete the Infinite Tsukuyomi himself, and create a world in which Rin lives."

This could be true if Black Zetsu wasn't there. He was the person planning everything in the dark.

Answer (score -1):

> It was never Madara's plan to begin with. He was manipulated by Black Zetsu.
>
> > **"Seeing them, Madara announces himself the world's saviour, one who has saved the world from itself by replacing the hells of reality with the heavens of dreams. While he is proselytising, Black Zetsu stabs him in the back. Black Zetsu reveals that it has never served Madara, but rather Kaguya Ōtsutsuki, and that it has manipulated him for decades in order to bring about her revival."** --- Quoted from [Kaguya Ōtsutsuki Strikes](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#Kaguya_.C5.8Ctsutsuki_Strikes).
>
> Black Zetsu is the person who delayed the plan.

Comment: Black Zetsu would have rushed the plan, as he wants his mother back.